# Can I skip some of the selected "Api Requests" in postman while using it through Newman-Runner-CLI?

Tags: postman, web-api-testing, postman-collection-runner, postman-testcase, postman-newman

As a user, I have several API collections created using postman and now I've integrated the Newman-Runner-CLI.

My question is that, is there any way to skip some of the selected API Requests from each collection, or is there is any way to add "Skipped API Requests" in a single file so during the execution process of Newman-Runner, it will automatically skip those added requests?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there's no way to find out if a collection is being run via Postman or Newman.

According to this thread, you could manually set a variable at the start of the execution ([see Postman forum](https://community.postman.com/t/is-there-a-way-to-tell-if-a-request-is-being-made-from-collection-runner-or-monitor/12081)).

You could then steer the execution with `postman.setNextRequest()` depending on the value of that variable. See: https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/building-workflows/

Comment: Thanks, Christian, Well as a user, once I run collection from Postman GUI so it simply asks me to tick/select API Requests which I want to execute. 

So, while running the same collection using Newman-Runner how can I skip those requests? Is there any way to do that or by adding some ignore API requests in some other file?

Comment: Just read my answer and the provided links, it's all explained there.